# Java Web App has a high rate of CPU consumption

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, processors

I'm new here and I'm not that very good in CPU consumption and Multi Threading. But I was wondering why my web app is consuming too much of the CPU process? What my program does is update values in the background so that users don't have to wait for the processing of the data and will only need to fetch it upon request. The updating processes are scheduled tasks using executor library that fires off 8 threads every 5 seconds to update my data.

Now I'm wondering why my application is consuming too much of the CPU. Is it because of bad code or is it because of a low spec server? (2 cores with 2 database and 1 major application running with my web app)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It's going to be near impossible unless you explain what the 8 threads are doing?  How many calculations?  How much IO?  Maybe show a small code sample?

Comment: This has to be possibly one of the most obscure questions I have seen in a while

Comment: Hey, downvoters, could you please explain why are you doing this? The question is legal. Yes, it is not well explained but be patient. This is the new user, he will learn how to ask good question. Do not punish him from the beginning!

Comment: I agree with AlexR.  The question is naive, but how is someone in the OP's position / experience going learn to ask non-naive questions if people are not prepared to answer him.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was naive. I'll try to provide some snippets of my code.. All I can say for now is, All 8 threads are querying a very much loaded DB(millions of transactions per table) and is encrypting and decrypting data afterwards. I am not really looking for any definite answer but more on how a 2 core server would perform in a very busy environment. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the DB in your clients' environment? If it is local, have you isolated CPU usage of the app from CPU usage of the DB? What does the DB actually look like. Anyway, the basic issue is the same: you need to profile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to profile your application to find out where the CPU is actually being consumed. [Java has some basic profiling methods built in](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/profiling/profiling_java5_threads_methodology.shtml), or if your environment permits it, you could run the built in "hprof" compiler:

java -Xrunhprof ...

(In reality, you probably want to set some extra options: Google "hprof" for more details.)

The latter is easier in principle, but I mention the possibility of adding your own profiling routine because it's more flexible and you can do it e.g. in a Servlet environment where running another profiler is more cumbersome.

Comment: I'll try this one on our dev environment.. Although what's bothering me is the fact that in any of our environments, it's not consuming much of the CPU process.. But in our clients environment, it is.. 2 cores vs 4 cores..

Comment: Well, it is possible for different configurations to "shift the balance of things" so that in one environment you see a CPU bottleneck that isn't evident in another environment. This is why I personally like the facility to embed "live" profiling in the live code then you can see what's actually going on rather than second-guessing on the basis of an entirely different setup.

Answer (score 1):

Paulo,

It is not possible for someone here to say whether the problem is that your code is inefficient or the server is under spec.  It could be either or both of those, or something else.

You are going to need to do some research of your own:

- Profile the code.  This will allow you to identify where your webapp is spending most of its time.
- Look at the OS-level stats that are available to you.  This might tell you that the real problem is memory usage or disk I/O.
- Look at the performance of the back-end database.  Is it using a lot of CPU?

Once you have identified the area(s) where the CPU is being used, you need to figure out the real cause of the problem is and work out how to fix it.  And once you've got a potential fix implemented, you can rerun your profiling, etc to see it has helped.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention this but the DB is consuming much more than my application.. But after timing each process, it's fast in completing each task.. Haven't profiled it though..